# Custom field type "media" not allowing PDFs

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field

Joomla media allows me to upload ".pdf" files.

But if I set up a "media" custom field it does not allow me neither to upload a PDF nor to select a PDF previously uploaded via the media manager (PDFs simply do not show on the select popup).

I'm I missing something on definitions? Or is this intended behavior?

Comment: Most probably you are not missing anything on this, it looks like it is intended, only image files can be added with this custom field at the moment. But what is your purpose with this field actually? Do you want to attach to or embed in an article or what else?

Comment: @Zollie Sorry for the late reply. I just hoped I had the same behavior as in com_media and allow users to attach a PDF or some other authorized file for that matter.